# When archiving in xcode 15, "No module in question 'ExpoModulesCore'"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, xcode15

No module in question 'ExpoModulesCore'

I pressed archive in xcode to distribute the code I worked with reactnative. But there's an error. When running 'npx react-native run-ios', it is operated on a physical device or simulator.

Comment: Is it a bare or an managed project ?
What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i just want to release app store

Comment: Why you don't use ```eas build -p ios```